# TeamCity: E-mail Notification to user which committed changes, that causes a build in the build chain to fail

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have a TeamCity project which includes 2 configurations:
-BuildConfig1: Triggered by SVN changes
-BuildConfig2: Triggeres by successful build of BuildConfig1

I need to send out notifications if BuildConfig2 fails. But only to users which has committed changes to BuildConfig1.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

In BuildConfig2, go to Version Control Settings, then under Checkout Options there is a Display Option called "Show changes from snapshot dependencies".

Checking it apparently does not only change what's displayed, but also propagates notification settings from the build(s) that produced snapshot dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Subscribing+to+Notifications

Under Notification Conditions see 'Ignore failures not caused by my changes'

Comment: As I understand, this setting will only notify the user if the build, where changes is made, fails. The user should be notified if any of the builds in the build chain fails. The build configurations in the build chain, is not configured with the same SVN root.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to create some sort of franken-build using the TeamCity REST API.

Have a build step corresponding to each of the full builds that will always execute after one of the builds runs. Then in the step `1` check if last execution of build `A` finished successfully and repeat for each additional build in the build chain.